# How to calculate the real time RPM of motor with rotary encoder?

Tags: motion, forward-kinematics, quadrature-encoder

I want to measure the real time RPM of the wheels. I think incremental rotary encoder would be good. But i am confused on how to interface it with DC brushless geared motors. From the images i am not quite sure if only one rotary encoder would suffice or do i need any other sensor also with it?
I am doing my project on arduino uno.

Comment: This seems like pretty basic math. If you know the number of cycles per revolution of the encoder you just divide. Why would you need another sensor?

Comment: @Octopus : In the image of rotary encoder, i couldn't see where the sensors are located, hence i was doubtful. Besides, i also couldn't find a video describing how to interface it with the wheels.

Comment: So is your question then, more about how to use the device? That sounds like a different question. More info about the device could help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Different encoders will attach to the motor or shaft differently.  Typically, the motor has a small shaft coming out the back of motor for this purpose.  And you buy the motor with the encoder already installed.

Actually, now i see you asked about a *brushless* motor.  Typically, these have added hall effect sensors by the manufacturer.  Because you energize the 3 coils of the motor in a specific sequence to spin it, it is easy to use these hall effect sensors as an incremental encoder.